# Decode from Escaped Unicode to Arabic using Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, unicode-escapes

I was trying to decode a json file that has escaped unicode text `/uHHH` .. the original text is Arabic

my research lead me to the following code using python.

```
s = '\u00d8\u00b5\u00d9\u0088\u00d8\u00b1 \u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u0084\u00d9\u008a\u00d9\u0088\u00d9\u0085\u00d9\u008a\u00d8\u00a7\u00d8\u00aa'
ouy= s.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
print(ouy)
```

the result text will be: `ØµÙØ± Ø§ÙÙÙÙÙØ§Øª`
which still needs some fix using [online tool](https://www.iosart.com/tools/charset-fixer/?source-text=%C3%98%C2%B5%C3%99%C2%88%C3%98%C2%B1%20%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%C2%84%C3%99%C2%8A%C3%99%C2%88%C3%99%C2%85%C3%99%C2%8A%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%98%C2%AA%0D%0A&input-encoding=UTF-8) to become the original text: `صور اليوميات`

Is there any way to perform that fix using the above code?
Would appreciate your help guys, thanks in advance

Comment: `ouy= s.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')` this worked for me

Comment: wow that was too simple, thanks .. that would help alot

Answer (score -1):

you can use this script to update all JSON files

```
import json

filename = 'YourFile.json'  # file name we want to compress

newname = filename.replace('.json', '.min.json')  # Output file name

with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as fp:
print("Compressing file: " + filename)
print('Compressing...')

jload = json.load(fp)
newfile = json.dumps(jload, indent=None, separators=(',', ':'), ensure_ascii=False)
newfile = newfile.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8') # remove this
#print(newfile)

with open(newname, 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:  # add encoding="utf8"
    f.write(newfile)

print('Compression complete!')
```

[DecodeJsonToOrigin](https://github.com/Matarwy/DecodeJsonToOrigin)